# Scala: from f(x1, ... xn) create x1 => f(x2, ..., xn)

Tags: scala, functional-programming

If we restrict it to the case of three parameters, I want to get from this

```
val f = (x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) => x + y + z
```

to this:

```
val g = (x: Int) => { (y: Int, z: Int) => f(x, y, z) }
```

I don't even know how that operation is called, presumably "curry the first parameter"?

Does Scala have utility function for this operation, or is writing it out like above the only way to achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Out of the box, there is only `.curried` which curries all arguments:

```
val f = (x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) => x + y + z

f.curried // Int => Int => Int => Int
```

However, you could use `_` syntax to make your code slightly shorter:

```
(x: Int) => f(x, _, _) // Int => (Int, Int) => Int
```

If you really need to use it often, you could implement some extension methods yourself

```
// Scala 2
implicit class Function3CurryFirstOps[A, B, C, D](private val f: (A, B, C) => D) extends AnyVal {
  def curriedFirst: A => (B => C) => D = (a: A) => f(a, _, _)
}

// Scala 3
extension [A, B, C, D](f: (A, B, C) => D)
  def curriedFirst: A => (B => C) => D = (a: A) => f(a, _, _)
```